# related name in Django abstract model using python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

When I use `%(app_label)s_%(class)s` in related name using Python3.4 I got the following error

```
    'app_label': cls._meta.app_label.lower()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'dict'
```

is there another way for that ?

edit

```
class TimeStampModel(models.Model):     

    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by" ,)
    edited_by =  models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_edited_by" ,  blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using.

Comment: I added the exact code

Comment: Strange that your `self.rel.related_name` attribute is a bytes when all I can see suggests it'd be a `str` object instead.

Comment: it works fine in python2.7